# Assertion failure after Xcode update to 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7.3

I updated my Xcode to 7.3. Before update I was able to run my code with any errors or crashes. After update I get assertion error when I run the below code on iPhone (Interesting no error on simulator).

```
let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil)
self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController!
```

**Error**

```
2016-03-24 16:15:25.891 Zilingo[434:92251] *** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.60.7/UIStoryboard.m:171
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 5.1.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Am I missing some step of the update ?

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: Make sure the name of the storyboard is correct. It is a bit wierd for me that the storyboard variable has the same name as the string you are using.

Comment: I made two variables different. Still the issues is still there. One interesting observation is it only shows error when I run it on iPhone and not on simulator

Comment: try to reset simulator then run.

Comment: The error comes when I run it on iPhone and no error on simulator.

Comment: unCheck break point then try.

Comment: Try clean, delete derived data and maybe change the `initialViewController` in storyboard.

Comment: maybe... this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31642838/1702413

Answer (score 1):

```
Try to this format:-   

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

   // get your storyboard
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

   // instantiate your desired ViewController
   let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! UIViewController

   // Because self.window is an optional you should check it's value first and assign your rootViewController
   if let window = self.window {
      window.rootViewController = rootController
   }

   return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case I forgot to add identifier string.
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("") as! UIViewController

I wrote like above. I forgot to add identifier. After I added identifier and it worked.